# Raspberry Pi 4B HDMI0 producing red / pink screen with flickering pixels and colorbanding

Tags: pi-4, hdmi

My *Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4* started having a red and pink output on its first HDMI (`HDMI0`) output. Sometimes the pixels flicker, "glitch". Especially black color seems to be misrepresented as red:

Example `HDMI0` output on a *Philips 22 PFL 5614 H/12* Full HD TV screen:
[image: Pinkish display on my Raspberry Pi 4B's HDMI0 output with glitchy pixels on a Philips 22 PFL 5614 H/12 TV screen]

Example `HDMI0` output on a *Elecrow RC070P* WSVGA screen:
[image: Reddish colorbanding along photo gradients and glitchy pixel flickering on my Raspberry Pi 4B's HDMI0 output with a Elecrow RC070P monitor]

Another example `HDMI0` output on a *Elecrow RC070P* WSVGA screen:
[image: Reddish glitchy columns where usually a black console screen is on my Raspberry Pi 4B's HDMI0 output with a Elecrow RC070P monitor]

I ruled out HDMI cable issues or monitor issues, as connecting the same cables/monitors to the second HDMI (`HDMI1`) output shows a good picture.

The red color presents itself immediately when booting happens. Starting with a vanilla *Raspberry Pi OS* SD Card with default `/boot/config.txt` settings also does not resolve this issue.

Updating to the latest EEPROM version also did not help:

```
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update 
BOOTLOADER: up to date
   CURRENT: Tue 08 Feb 2022 05:24:46 PM UTC (1644341086)
    LATEST: Tue 08 Feb 2022 05:24:46 PM UTC (1644341086)
   RELEASE: stable (/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/stable)
            Use raspi-config to change the release.

  VL805_FW: Using bootloader EEPROM
     VL805: up to date
   CURRENT: 000138a1
    LATEST: 000138a1
```

So I assume a fault with the `HDMI0` onboard connector. Is there a chance to investigate further and maybe repair it myself? Or maybe there are workarounds to try out - changing HDMI "boost" settings or something?

Comment: `black color seems to be misrepresented as red` ... does not look like a misrepresentation ... looks like red is always on

Comment: Have you tried a different hdmi cable?